# mean and SD of directions (in degrees) in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, angle, summary

I'm working on a model in NetLogo where I would like to report the mean and standard deviation of a set of turtle dispersal directions (bearings from 0-360 degrees) in each year of the simulation. Of course there's no default command in NetLogo for these circular statistics, so I'll need to write out the calculations by hand. I'm wondering if anyone has worked out a similar custom function in NetLogo before?

I've come across this set of code for calculating the mean:

```
to-report mean-of-headings [headings]
  let x-mean mean map [sin ?] headings
  let y-mean mean map [cos ?] headings
  if x-mean = 0 and y-mean = 0 [ report random 360 ]
  report atan x-mean y-mean
end
```

But I'm not positive if that will do for the mean, and haven't seen code for the SD. My thought was to translate this R code into NetLogo language, and create a reporter similar to the one above?

```
Tester <-c(340, 360, 20) # list of bearings

sine = sum(sin(Tester * pi/180)) # sin of each angle, convert to radian first
cosine = sum(cos(Tester * pi/180)) # cos of each angle, convert to radian first

Tester_mean = (atan2(sine, cosine) * 180/pi) %% 360

mu = (Tester - Tester_mean + 180) %% 360 - 180 # Difference of each angle from mean
Tester_sd = sqrt(sum(mu^2)/(length(Tester) - 1)) # Standard Deviation

Tester_mean # mean bearing
Tester_sd # sd bearing
```